# Using special tilde characters in title of AppActivate

Tags: python, character-encoding, special-characters, pywin32

I'm using python with the pywin32 library to activate a window and send some keys to it. Something like:

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell") 
shell.AppActivate(self.software)
shell.SendKeys(self.gkey)
```

The self.software variable indicates to which window i'm sending the key. It's working perfectly fine with Notepad, WordPad, Outlook, etc. However, the On-Screen Keyboard window that in portuguese is "Teclado no Ecrã" doesn't seem to work with the AppActivate function because of the special character "ã".

How should I encode the self.software string title to work in these situations? Note that I'm receiving the self.software string from a web platform.

Thanks in advance.